# Reading BLE data using cc2540 dongle with BTool - I get different data than using native ble with python Bleak

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this code using Bleak:

```
characteristic_data = "0000ff31-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
characteristic_command = "0000ff21-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

def start():
    await self.client.start_notify(characteristic_data , cb1)
    await self.client.start_notify(characteristic_command, cb2)
    await self.client.write_gatt_char(characteristic_command,bytearray([0x80, 0x04, 0x15]),response=True) # send command to the device to start send data

def cb1():
    await self.client.write_gatt_char(characteristic_command,bytearray([0x80,0x04, 0x17]),response=False) # send ack for the device so it knows we got the data and we want more

def cb2():
    await self.client.stop_notify(characteristic_command)
```

This works ok and I get data bytes like this for example:
32088200001303D9011303CD011203CE011C03CC010000

With BTool I do this:
I write '01:00' in 0x001D and 0x0022 (where the Uuid is one after oxFF21 and one after 0xFF31 like shown here:
[image]
Then I write '0x80, 0x04, 0x15' to '0x001C' (Uuid 0xFF21).
I start get data in the data field (0x0021 - Uuid 0xFF31).
But here, I get a shorter data, like this:
3217F80000790327027503270276031D02890320 (In the picture you see '11' because this is the last message sent)
Three bytes less than when using Bleak.
This happens only for one type of data that I get. For shorter data packets I get the same length using both ways.

Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you saying with BTool you are getting 20 bytes and with Bleak you are getting 23 bytes. Is that correct? And which do you believe is correct? In BLE 4.0 I think the data packet length was limited to 20 bytes. From BLE 4.2 that was increased. Are both tools using the same dongles?

Comment: @ukBaz You're correct. The 23 is the correct one for sure. The 23 is from my windows 11 laptop, without a dongle, it has version 5 (LMP 11.9749). I'm trying to find out the version for the dongle. I guess this is the cause, thanks!